# Xcode 8 & Swift 3 -- Adding a 'status bar' feature when user exits app?

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

I was using an app called "sleep cycle" the other day and noticed that when I exit the app (and an alarm is set) a status bar appears prompting me to return.

I want to implement this feature in an app I'm currently working on, but do not know where to start/what the feature is even called. I have included an image of it below. Any input/advice is appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This red bar is a system level bar shown to indicate the app is recording audio while in the background.

iOS uses different colors to indicate different things (the bar is green when on a phone call, for instance).

In order to implement this in your own app, you need to be recording audio in the background. The system will then show the bar to the user while the audio is being recorded. To add the audio background mode to your app, add the following key to your Info.plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Comment: have used this app also and was wondering the same, great answer thanks!